# Replace a CSS of one site to a similar CSS of another one

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, css

How I can replace a CSS file for the scifi stack exchange site https://scifi.stackexchange.com/ with the CSS of this site https://diy.stackexchange.com/ as its blue color comforts my eye. Is there any chrome extension or work around to achieve this?

Comment: [StackExchange Theme Switcher](http://stackapps.com/q/2808)

Comment: Although it is not the way I asked to change the theme, but it actually a perfect answer so please post it as answer to vote up and accept it :)

Comment: done, added as an answer @wazery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are couple of a Chrome Extensions, [Stylish](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe) and [StyleBot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/kaifpdafpkbjghohkfkfmkcfcmmnbnaa) which allow for designing of themes and style individual elements.

While Stylish relies on [userstyles](http://userstyles.org/) for custom styles, Stylebot has a an inbuilt sharing tool for share and fetch custom style sheets for most sites.

---

For this specific Stack Exchange, [there's a userscript](https://stackapps.com/q/2808) which allows you to swap stylesheets for any Stack Exchange site *from* any Stack Exchange site.

[image]

---

Note that the stylesheets are swapped *after* the page has loaded, so there will be a momentary flash where the original stylesheet is shown and then the new one is swapped. If you have a fast enough connection, this will probably be not noted by you.

---

Finally, recent Chrome update allows you to install userscripts & extensions via 1 click *only* from the Chrome WebStore.

To install the above linked userscript, you'll have to download/save the `.user.js` file, open `chrome://chrome/extensions/` (or Click on Chrome Menu → Tools → Extensions ) & drag the `*.user.js` file to the Extensions tab. After that, you'll get the prompt to install the extension.